# Embed Special Folder in SQL Compact connection string?

Tags: sql-server-ce

I am creating a SQL Compact demo, and I want to point the connection string in my App.config file to %CommonAppDataFolder% (the Special Folder token that points to `c:\ProgramData` on Windows 7 machines). My current connection string hard-codes the `ProgramData` folder reference:

```
Data Source=c:\ProgramData\Foresight Systems\SQL Compact Demo\LocalData.sdf
```

I'd like to change it to something like this:

```
Data Source=%CommonAppDataFolder%\Foresight Systems\SQL Compact Demo\LocalData.sdf
```

Obviously, that doesn't work. So, my question is: What is the correct syntax to embed a Special Folder in a connection string? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the [answer here](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/thread-3848466.php), I have come to the conclusion that it simply can't be done. If anyone knows of a way to embed a Special Folder token in a connection string in App.config, I'll be happy to change the accepted answer.